# Want android app to wait until user presses a button before continuing

Tags: android

I have a game for android, and when the user wins, it shows a dialog asking if they want to play again.  If they say "no", the application exits, and if they say "yes", it starts another game.  The problem is that a new game starts as the dialog is displayed, instead of waiting for the user to press a button.  The code is like this:

```
if (won) {
    showDialog(DIALOG_WON_ID);
    imageAdapter.initializemThumbIds();  // this starts a new game
}
```

I don't want the start-new-game line to execute until the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this call

```
imageAdapter.initializemThumbIds();
```

Into the "yes" button click event.

EDIT:

Something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Would you like to play again?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               imageAdapter.initializemThumbIds();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
               // Exit the game
           } 
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();   
alert.show();
```

Comment: He means `if (won) { showDialog }` then set an onclick listener for the dialog button, and make the dialog button start the new game.

Comment: also, use more descriptive names for your methods `imageAdapter.initializemThumbIds()` doesn't sound like it starts a new game.

Comment: @MatthewRudy Thanks for helping out, but unfortunately I don't understand your comment (the one about setting an onclick listener).  Point taken about descriptive names though.

Comment: @SpencerRuport You sound like you know what you're talking about, so perhaps I've done something silly elsewhere in my code which is messing things up, but I can't put the imageAdapter line in my onClick function without it complaining that "imageAdapter cannot be resolved".

Comment: @BenH - Well that's clearly an issue with scope. I assume that you've pasted this code into your method `showDialog` which of course won't be able to resolve `imageAdapter` to the object which was defined in the procedure where the `if(won)` statement resides. You either need to pass `imageAdapter` to the `showDialog` method or you need to make it a global variable. Additionally you might have to declare a final version of the `imageAdapter` object so that you can use it in the `onClick` method. We're getting into fairly remedial territory here so perhaps you should read up on Java scoping.

Comment: @SpencerRuport I got my scoping problem worked out, and this worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your current code displays the dialog and immediately proceeds to the line following `showDialog()`. What you want to do is move the code that starts a new game to the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` code of the `Dialog` implemented in `showDialog()`.